# Easiest way to get time between TouchesMoved method calls

Tags: time, cocos2d-x, touchesmoved

I've been searching for easy way to get time step between TouchedMoved method calls in cocos2d-x, but so far I find nothing.. Could you help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it directly with the C++ primitives, follow this link:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/

You'll find a sample script which demonstrates how to calculate difference between two times.

Another way is to sum the delta time of the `update` method into an instance var, like this:

```
void YourClass::update(float dt)
{
    m_timer += dt;
}
```

Then in your onTouchBegin, onTouchMoved and onTouchEnded methods get the value of m_timer and count the difference. For example:

```
void YourClass::onTouchBegin(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event) {
   float m_beginTime = m_timer;
}

void YourClass::onTouchEnded(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event) {
   float m_endTime = m_timer;
   float time_diff = m_endTime - m_beginTime;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I did the trick with schedule, but it's not safe enough. I'm pretty sure there should be a way to do it for ccTouchesMoved method. I'm looking for some very standard and neat solution.

Comment: Why not safe? I always use it for time based stuff

Comment: It's not safe, because there's a possibility that oldTime will be equal with currentTime, I've checked it

Comment: Understood. With this method you can obtain a precision of about 0.01 ms. Otherwise you have to use the standard c++ libs I mentioned above, these are more faithful.

Comment: Agree :) Thx for the help, I appreciate it